# javascript 'this' in ES6 classes return undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I think this is a scope problem, but I'm not sure how to fix this. 
Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9k9Pe/1498/

```
class FrameCreator{

    constructor(){
        this.createFrame();
    }
    createFrame(){
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      this.iframe = iframe;
      var frameLoaded=this.frameLoaded;
      iframe.onload = function () {
                    frameLoaded();
      };
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    frameLoaded(){
            console.log("frame loaded");
    }
}

class CustomFrameCreator extends FrameCreator{
    addContent(){
            console.log(this); // returns the object
    }
    frameLoaded(){
            console.log(this); // returns undefined
    }
}

var frame=new CustomFrameCreator();
frame.addContent();
```

`frameLoaded()` prints undefined, while `addContent` prints the object.

How to fix this, so I can have a reference in this when frame is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Try `iframe.onload = () => this.frameLoaded();`

Comment: `var frameLoaded=this.frameLoaded;` don't do that, for starters. or at least bind it.

Comment: It's not clear which `frameLoaded` method you want to run at `iframe.onload`, and with which `this` value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another alternative to `.bind()` is to use ES6 Arrow function to preserve context:

```
iframe.onload = () => {
  this.frameLoaded();
};
```

```js
class FrameCreator {
  constructor() {
    this.createFrame();
  }
  
  createFrame() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    this.iframe = iframe;
    
    iframe.onload = () => {
      this.frameLoaded();
    };

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
  
  frameLoaded() {
    console.log("frame loaded");
  }
}

class CustomFrameCreator extends FrameCreator {
  addContent() {
    console.log(this); // returns the object
  }
  frameLoaded() {
    console.log(this); // returns the object now
  }
}

var frame = new CustomFrameCreator();
frame.addContent();
```

Comment: This creates a function that calls the function. I suspect it is not as efficient as bind. Not sure though.

Comment: @frodeborli `bind()` wraps the function internally, anyway, this is how you would implement the polyfill. The part that makes it less efficient is actually the scoped reference to `this`, which kills some JavaScript optimization potential on the function scope, so you're partially correct, but for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 7):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function to bind context

```
this.frameLoaded.bind(this);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr73r1db/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the handler for `onload`

```
iframe.onload = function () {
  this.frameLoaded();
}.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating a new scope, `this` within the `onload` callback does not reference your class, it instead references the callback function itself. You must [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your `frameLoaded` method to the proper thisArg.

```js
class FrameCreator {

  constructor() {
    this.createFrame();
  }
  createFrame() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    this.iframe = iframe;
    var frameLoaded = this.frameLoaded;
    iframe.onload = frameLoaded.bind(this)
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
  frameLoaded() {
    console.log("frame loaded");
  }
}

class CustomFrameCreator extends FrameCreator {
  addContent() {
    console.log(this); // returns the object
  }
  frameLoaded() {
    console.log(this); // returns undefined
  }
}

var frame = new CustomFrameCreator();
frame.addContent();
```